# How to Manage Role Based User Rights using asp.net & MSSQL?

Tags: sql, asp.net

I have multiple asp.net web form and sql express database.
In web form there are 3 types of action needs to be controlled from Menu

```
 ADD, DELETE , EDIT.
```

I wan to create custom User role to specify user rights to manage access control of 
asp.net c#  Application 
(Menu, ADD,DELETE and EDIT  visibility).

Currently i am try to manage using simple sql reader query on every page for every button and link.

```
 string yes = "1";
 if (rdr["access"].ToString() == yes.ToString())
    Button1.Visible = true;
```

Comment: Welcome to stackoverflow.com.
Please take some time to read the [help pages](http://stackoverflow.com/help), especially the sections named ["What topics can I ask about here?"](http://stackoverflow.com/help/on-topic) and
["What types of questions should I avoid asking?"](http://stackoverflow.com/help/dont-ask).
Also please [take the tour](http://stackoverflow.com/tour) and read about [how to ask good questions](https://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask).
Lastly please read [this question checklist](https://codeblog.jonskeet.uk/2012/11/24/stack-overflow-question-checklist/).

Comment: So... What part of this are you asking for help with? The data structure or the back-end C# logic?

Comment: I am new in asp.net so if possible then please suggest both.

Comment: FYI, this type of question - "How to design and implement a large feature of an application + a corresponding data model" - is way too broad for SO.

Comment: So just sugges me only c# code

Comment: Or give other suggestions

Answer (score 0):

You will need the following SQL tables:

```
CREATE TABLE Roles
(
    Rolename Text (255) NOT NULL,
    ApplicationName Text (255) NOT NULL, 
    CONSTRAINT PKRoles PRIMARY KEY (Rolename, ApplicationName)
)

CREATE TABLE UsersInRoles
(
    Username Text (255) NOT NULL,
    Rolename Text (255) NOT NULL,
    ApplicationName Text (255) NOT NULL,
    CONSTRAINT PKUsersInRoles PRIMARY KEY (Username, Rolename, ApplicationName)
)
```

Then build the Role Provider class

You can use EF or ADO.NET to implement the methods

```
public class SqlRoleProvider: RoleProvider
{
    public override void Initialize(string name, NameValueCollection config)
    {
        // 
        // Initialize values from web.config. 
        // 
    }

    public override void AddUsersToRoles(string[]  usernames, string[] rolenames)
    {
    }

    public override void CreateRole(string rolename)
    {
    }

    public override bool DeleteRole(string rolename, bool throwOnPopulatedRole)
    {

    }

    public override string[] GetAllRoles()
    {

    }

    public override string[] GetRolesForUser(string username)
    {

    }

    public override string[] GetUsersInRole(string rolename)
    {

    }

    public override bool IsUserInRole(string username, string rolename)
    {

    }

    public override void RemoveUsersFromRoles(string[] usernames, string[] rolenames)
    {

    }

    public override bool RoleExists(string rolename)
    {

    }

    public override string[] FindUsersInRole(string rolename, string usernameToMatch)
    {

    }

}
```

The you must set it up in web.config

```
<configuration>
  <connectionStrings>
    <add name="SqlServices" connectionString="DSN=RolesDSN;" />
  </connectionStrings>

  <system.web>
    <authentication mode="Forms" />
      <forms loginUrl="loginvb.aspx"
        name=".ASPXFORMSAUTH" />
    </authentication>

    <authorization>
      <deny users="?" />
    </authorization>

    <roleManager defaultProvider="SqlRoleProvider" 
      enabled="true"
      cacheRolesInCookie="true"
      cookieName=".ASPROLES"
      cookieTimeout="30"
      cookiePath="/"
      cookieRequireSSL="false"
      cookieSlidingExpiration="true"
      cookieProtection="All" >
      <providers>
        <clear />
        <add
          name="SqlRoleProvider"
          type="Samples.AspNet.Roles.SqlRoleProvider"
          connectionStringName="SqlServices" 
          applicationName="SampleApplication" 
          writeExceptionsToEventLog="false" />
      </providers>
    </roleManager>

  </system.web>
</configuration>
```

There is the Sample Role Provider on Microsoft:

**Configuration and database schema:**

https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/tksy7hd7.aspx

**Sample implementation for OLEDB (access database), you can change the implementation to use SQL Database using SqlConnection, SqlCommand, SqlDataReader...**

https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/317sza4k.aspx